# Questions about using the interrail pass from Rotterdam to Budapest

Tags: trains, europe, interrail

So, I bit the bullet and bought an interrail pass. Planning to go from Rotterdam (Dec. 26th) to Budapest.

Here are the details of the route:

1. 07.35-08.12 Rotterdam Centraal - Utrecht Centraal (IC 625)
2. 08.34-11.50 Utrecht Centraal - Frankfurt Flughafen (ICE 105)
3. 12.01-18.47 Frankfurt Flughafen - Wien Hauptbahnhof (ICE 27)
4. 19.42-22.02 Wien Hauptbahnhof - Budapest (EC 40347)

From the Rail Planner app, I only see an option to reserve a seat for the Utrecht - Frankfurt train, is this correct? All of these trains are run by Deutsche Bahn, I think, which from experience does require seat reservations. Though I have also never needed to reserve seats before for trains to and from Vienna.

Also, I'm a bit worried about the transit in Frankfurt. If I miss the transit due to my train being delayed, do I need to reserve another seat again for the next train to Vienna? Also, that means I have to spend the night in Vienna, could I get a compensation from DB for that?

Another thing, I remembered reading somewhere that I can use the interrail pass ONCE in a country to get where I want to start my journey, yes? That means I don't need to buy a ticket to get to Utrecht from Rotterdam?

Comment: The nice thing about a pass like interrail is the flexibility -- you can pretty much hop on any train as necessary. Spend some time with the schedules and prepare some alternatives, so if something goes wrong, you know what exactly to do. e.g. there's definitely ICE29/rjx261 option 2 hours later. For this, I find it better to plan it segment-by-segment. For longer trips the search engines often only show few options they consider as best, and a lot of additional possibilities remain hidden.

Comment: I would definitely reserve seats on December 26 as the trains may be very busy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> From the Rail Planner app, I only see an option to reserve a seat for the Utrecht - Frankfurt train, is this correct? All of these trains are run by Deutsche Bahn, I think, which from experience does require seat reservations. Though I have also never needed to reserve seats before for trains to and from Vienna.

That's not quite right; the first train from Rotterdam to Utrecht is run by Nederlandse Spoorwegen. The next 2 are Deutsche Bahn. Your last train from Vienna to Budapest is interesting, it's a set of carriages owned by MÁV which are attached to the back of the Dacia Express overnight sleeper train [which is mostly run by CFR Călători] from Vienna to Bucharest in order to provide an evening train from Vienna to Budapest.

With that set aside, none of the trains require any reservation. In fact very few Deutsche Bahn trains require any reservation, even high speed ICE trains, it's just a few international routes -- your train between Utrecht and Frankfurt is not one that requires reservations.

That said though you may wish to make a seat reservation - I'd imagine many trains would be pretty busy on Boxing Day. For Deutsche Bahn you can make them at https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/en?&rit=yes -- by going direct to train operating companies you can save the extra fees charged when you go through the Rail Planner app.

---

> Also, I'm a bit worried about the transit in Frankfurt. If I miss the transit due to my train being delayed, do I need to reserve another seat again for the next train to Vienna? Also, that means I have to spend the night in Vienna, could I get compensation from DB for that?

I don't know if there are any specific extra German rules that would allow you to get compensation from Deutsche Bahn. Interrail passes are considered though a single ticket - and you are making an international journey so you would get some protection through CIV -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIV_(rail_travel). The full regulations are at https://cit-rail.org/secure-media/files/documentation_de/passenger/civ/civ1999-f-d-e.pdf?cid=224515 and include under Article 32:

> The carrier shall be liable to the
> passenger for loss or damage
> resulting from the fact that, by reason
> of cancellation, the late running of a
> train or a missed connection, his
> journey cannot be continued the same
> day, or that a continuation of the
> journey the same day could not
> reasonably be required because of
> given circumstances. The damages
> shall comprise the reasonable costs of
> accommodation as well as the
> reasonable costs occasioned by
> having to notify persons expecting the
> passenger.

I'll add if you read down that there are some exceptions to this -- and that exactly what is "reasonable" is left up to local rules & regulations. It can also be incredibly difficult (if sometimes impossible) to exercise these rights in practice.

It should also be noted that under CIV rules "carrier" does not mean the company that runs the train - article 3 defines it as:

> “carrier” means the contractual carrier
> with whom the passenger has
> concluded the contract of carriage
> pursuant to these Uniform Rules, or a
> successive carrier who is liable on the
> basis of this contract;

So basically you'd likely be claiming against wherever you bought the train ticket from, not Deutsche Bahn. Your ticket will have a code somewhere -- most (possibly all?) interrail passes will say "CIV 9901" -- like this: https://twitter.com/chantall40/status/957604653344182272 -- which means you'd need to claim against https://interrail.eu/en/ If you have a different code you can check it at https://uic.org/IMG/pdf/codification_4n_22112018.pdf (left hand most column)

I'll stress again that exercising CIV rights in practice can be very tricky, if you do think you'll have any issue with connections I'd strongly encourage you to speak to members of staff as soon as possible. I'll also add though that there are later trains between Vienna and Budapest, none of which require a reservation, so you can get a later one if needed as long as you are not delayed too much.

Interrail do have a form at https://www.interrail.eu/en/support/delay-compensation which allows you to claim some money back for longer delays. But I note in the terms for using this it says around hotels:

> Claims for reimbursement of expenses incurred as a result of sustained delay, e.g. for alternative means of transportation, accommodation, etc., fall outside this policy. Such claims should be submitted directly to the railway undertaking where the delay was incurred.

My own view from reading those is that this condition on their compensation form is in violation of the CIV rights that should take precedence, but I'll defer to anyone else with more knowledge or experience.

---

> Another thing, I remembered reading somewhere that I can use the interrail pass ONCE in a country to get where I want to start my journey, yes? That means I don't need to buy a ticket to get to Utrecht from Rotterdam?

The term for this is the inbound and outbound journey -- https://www.interrail.eu/en/interrail-passes/what-is-interrail/travel-your-own-country -- these are 2 days which you can use to upgrade an existing travel day so your pass can also be used in your home country. You can use as many trains in your home country as you need to and still only use up one of your inbound/outbound journeys. So yes you can use your outbound journey to cover both trains out of the Netherlands without needing to buy a separate ticket.

---

As a final bit of advice I'd strongly encourage you to confirm the times of those trains directly with the operating companies, I think that is always good advice but particularly when traveling on 26th December. The Rail Planner app is not always fully accurate -- and particularly with things like engineering works (which in some areas is more common at Christmas) and with operators that run a non-standard timetable it can sometimes provide incorrect information.

Comment: There are a couple of things not correct here.
The Carrier is whoever is operating the train you are on. So it will be NS till the Dutch - German Border, then DB till the Austrian border, OBB From there on till Hungary and then MAV. International tickets usually display the codes of the carriers involved. And apart from a few exceptions that is always the national railways of the countries involved. In case of disrutption it is the carrier of the train that you are on that should take care of you.

Comment: Have you got any resources that you'd recommend on CIV @Krist van Besie - its defiantly the area I'm least knowledge about and there isn't too much I've seen online beyond the PDFs. I'd gladly accept your edits if you can improve them. Though I'm not sure I'm immediately convinced by those as the list of operators? Sure DB operate the ICE train for its whole route from Utrecht Centraal - Frankfurt Flughafen. I know with some EC routes its more complicated. Even if its staffed with NS staff onboard (no idea if it is). A quick sample of international tickets I have all only have 1 civ code.

Comment: NS operates  the ICE till Arnhem, and only there DB takes over. The same thing is the case with many other international trains. You can check that for yourself on www.bahn.de if you want. 
Regarding CIV codes: Normally there will be one on the top left, under the Logo of whoever sold you the ticket. Then there will be codes at other places. Often there is a "transporter" or "befoerderer" mentioned, with more codes, and there are codes in the via field. These codes can all be different. For example if you buy a ticket from Amsterdam to Koeln at an SBB station...

Comment: Reading the delay compensation policy makes me feel like it's even more complex. To claim anything, you might have to have a reservation booked via Interrail for the missed connection (i.e. for Frankfurt-Wien in that case). And the total delay should be longer than one hour.  The table of compensations shows the fraction of the pass price you can get, which seems to roughly average to less than 10 euros. These comments mostly confirm what you say "It can also be incredibly difficult (sometimes impossible) to exercise these rights in practice".